# Relation between $(A/I)^G$ and $A/I^G$ for a group action $G\curvearrowright A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, affine-varieties

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I\subset A$ be an ideal.

Moreover, for a group $G$, we are given group action $G\curvearrowright A$ such that
$g(I)=I$ for any $g\in G.$ Then, naturally $G$ acts on $A/I$.

Now, ideal $I^G:=\langle a \in I\mid g\cdot a=a (\forall g\in G)\rangle\subset A$
and $(A/I)^G:=\{a\in A/I\mid g\cdot a=a (\forall g\in G)\}$.

I want to know the Relation between $(A/I)^G$ and $A/I^G$.

Especially, the case of $A=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $I=(f_1,\dots,f_m)$, and $G$ is finite abelian group.
Then $\operatorname{Spec}((A/I)^G)=V(f_1,\dots,f_m)/G\subset \mathbf{A}^n/G$.

On the other hand, $V(f_1,\dots,f_n)\subset\operatorname{Spec}(A/I^G)\subset \mathbf{A}^n$.

If we want to take a closed immersion $V(f_1,\dots,f_m)/G$ to $\mathbf{A}^n$, can we use
$\operatorname{Spec}(A/I^G)$ well?

Comment: $I^G$ need not be an ideal of $A$, but it is an ideal of $A^G$.  It seems more natural to compare $(A/I)^G$ to $A^G/I^G$.

Comment: Thank you. I rewrite the definition of $I^G$.